# Express $\mathbb{Z}$ as a direct limit of some rings with finite prime ideals

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

By Hochster's theorem, $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ can be expressed as an inverse limit of some finite $T_0$-spaces, hence the ring  $\mathbb{Z}$ should be able to be expressed as a direct limit of some rings with finite prime ideals. What is the expression? I did not figure out.

Comment: How do you know that the spaces arising in the inverse limit are also spectra? I don't think you can be sure that is the case.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff  Finite $T_0$ space is a trivial inverse limit of itself, hence by Hochster's theorem again it is spectral.

Comment: The topological space $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ is an inverse limit of finite $T_0$ spaces, but that doesn't imply that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a direct limit of rings with finite spectra, and I don't see anything in Hochster's work that would imply it is.

Comment: But still it would be interesting to see how to write $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ as an inverse limit of finite $T_0$ topological spaces. I can't see how to do that explicitly right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not true that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a direct limit of rings with finitely many prime ideals.  Indeed, if $f:A\to\mathbb{Z}$ is any homomorphism, the unique homomorphism $i:\mathbb{Z}\to A$ satisfies $fi=1_\mathbb{Z}$, so $i^*f^*:\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})\to \operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ is the identity.  In particular, the image of $i^*f^*$ is infinite, so the image of $f^*$ is infinite, so $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ must have infinitely many points.

What Hochster proved is that there exists an inverse system of finite topological spaces $X_i$ whose inverse limit is the space $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ and such that $X_i=\operatorname{Spec}(A_i)$ for some rings $A_i$.  However, this does not mean that the rings $A_i$ form a direct system with colimit $\mathbb{Z}$, for several reasons.  For one thing, the continuous maps $X_i\to X_j$ need not be the underlying maps of morphisms of schemes, so you don't necessarily get maps $A_j\to A_i$ of rings.  For another thing, even if you did get a direct system of rings, there is no reason its colimit would have to be $\mathbb{Z}$ (all you can say is that Spec of the colimit is has a canonical continuous map to $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$, which need not be a homeomorphism, let along the underlying map of an isomorphism of schemes).